# PhoneGap issue with returning to the application

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have developed an iphone App using Phonegap.Its working fine.One issue on my app, if i have visited any page in the App and return to the application menu, again i click the app icon it show the last visit page, not show the start up page.

Anybody know how i solve this isuue, Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I too faced the same issue. To start the App from start do this:

1. open your -info.plist.
2. Add 'Application does not run in background' to a field.
3. check the check box beside it.

Hope it helped you.